# Binary addition using char array

Tags: c++, output, addition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

    char Pbuf8[9]={"01100000"};
    char Mbuf4[10]={"01110000"};

    int num=0;
    char Snum[9]="0";   
    int carry=0;


    for(int c=7;c>=0;c--){

        //Convert a string to a number and add
        num=(Pbuf8[c]-'0')+(Mbuf4[c]-'0')+carry;

        //binary addition
        if(num==1){
            Snum[c]=num;
            carry=0;
        }else if(num==2){
            num=0;
            carry=1;
            Snum[c]=num;
        }else if(num==3){
            num=1;
            carry=1;
            Snum[c]=num;
        }
        //Convert num to string and store in Snum
        sprintf(Snum, "%d", num);  
    }
    //output
    printf("%s",Snum);
     

    return 0;
}
```

Calculate and output the sum of Pbuf8 and Mbuf4.

I want to output '00001011' but '1' is output.

If there is no 'sprintf(number, "%d", number);' does not exist, 'rr' is output.

How do I get the value I want?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like detailing the problems you have (expected versus actual output (for some specified input), or build errors).

Comment: If the problem isn't a build error, then I also suggest you learn how to use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. To help with debugging like this, also break complex expressions (for example `(Pbuf8[c]-'0')+(Mbuf4[c]-'0')+carry`) into simpler expressions storing intermediate results in temporary variables.

Comment: As a possible hint: `Snum[c]=num`? You know how to convert a digit character into its corresponding integer, but not the other way around?

Comment: BTW why your desired output is `0b00001011` for `0b01100000` + `0b01110000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 minor bugs in your code.

- Snum must be initialized with everything being 0. Otherwise it will just be filled with one 0 and the lower part of the addition will not be visible
- You need to convert "num" back to a number, before adding it back to the char array. So, `num+'0'`
- Delete the "sprintf", It will overwrite the previously created result.

The corrected code will look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

    char Pbuf8[9]={"01100000"};
    char Mbuf4[10]={"01110000"};

    int num=0;
    char Snum[9]="00000000";   
    int carry=0;


    for(int c=7;c>=0;c--){

        //Convert a string to a number and add
        num=(Pbuf8[c]-'0')+(Mbuf4[c]-'0')+carry;

        //binary addition
        if(num==1){
            Snum[c]=num+'0';
            carry=0;
        }else if(num==2){
            num=0;
            carry=1;
            Snum[c]=num+'0';
        }else if(num==3){
            num=1;
            carry=1;
            Snum[c]=num+'0';
        }
        //Convert num to string and store in Snum
        //sprintf(Snum, "%d", num);  
    }
    //output
    printf("%s",Snum);
     

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `if .. else` statement. Just calculate with `carry = num / 2; num = num % 2;`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I only corrected the bugs in the code. I did not change the algorithm. Maybe, I will add a C++ solution . . .

Comment: I got the results I wanted. Thank you very much:)